# Не работает pagination Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, owl-carousel

Не работают кнопки `owl-prev` `owl-next` `owl-dots`. У меня подключён jQuery 2.1.1.min.js . Не листают. Без понятия в чём причина,хотя по документации всё верно сделал(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<!-- OWL CAROUSEL CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/owl/docs/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/owl/docs/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

<!-- jQuery 2.1.1 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Секция №3 OWL CAROUSEL START -->
</head>
<body>
    <section class="sec3">


        <hr class="dot-line">
        <div class="w-100 text-center ">
            <h2 class="w-100 rd pt-5">Лучшие моменты творческих вечеров</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slider owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded text-center">
            <div class="owl-stage-outer">
                <div class="owl-stage">
                    <div class="owl-item">
                        <img src="images/owl-car-1.jpg" alt="something" class="item cust-img mx-auto">
                    </div>

                    <div class="owl-item">
                        <img src="images/owl-car-2.jpg" alt="something" class="item cust-img mx-auto">
                    </div>

                    <div class="owl-item">
                        <img src="images/owl-car-3.jpg" alt="something" class="item cust-img mx-auto">
                    </div>

                    <div class="owl-item">
                        <img src="images/owl-car-4.jpg" alt="something" class="item cust-img mx-auto">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="owl-controls">
                <div class="owl-nav">
        <div class="owl-prev" style="">prev</div>
        <div class="owl-next" style="">next</div>
    </div>
                <div class="owl-dots">
                    <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
                    <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
                    <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
                    <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <hr class="dot-line">
    </section>
<!-- jQuery OWL CAROUSEL -->
    <script src="js/owl/docs/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl/src/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl/src/js/owl.autoplay.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl/docs/assets/vendors/highlight.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl/docs/assets/js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- START OF OWL CAROUSEL -->
    <script src="js/owl-start.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<!-- Секция №3 OWL CAROUSEL END -->
```

```js
//это <script src="js/owl-start.js"></script>


$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
 loop:true,
 margin:10,
 nav : true,
   dots: true,
   pagination : true,
 autoplay:true,
 autoplayTimeout:7000,
 autoplayHoverPause:true,
 responsiveClass:true,
 responsive:{
     0:{
         items:1,
         nav:true
     },
     768:{
         items:2,
         nav:true
     },
     1000:{
         items:3,
         nav:true,
         loop:true
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: Сам плагин подключен?

Comment: Да. И библиотеки JS, CSS

Comment: Оформите пример с библиотекой.

Comment: [Здесь прямая](https://kei-evenings.ml/) ссылка на сайт где я применил Owl carousel, но кнопки-переключатели мне пришлось замаскировать анимацией свайпа влево до того момента когда не разберусь с pagination.